# How can I disable RN's WebView from jumping to the browser?

Tags: react-native

When I click on the link with `target="_blank"` in RN's WebView, it will jump to an external browser to continue. Is there any way to click on the link with `target="_blank"` and continue loading in the current RN WebView?

Don't want to inject js for removing target="_blank"

Comment: ```target="_blank" ``` why you don't remove this...

Comment: also only happen in android devices works just fine on IOS. Using expo project setup

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe too late to reply on this thread but I spent a lot of time debugging this and found a solution so posting it so that it helps others

```
setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
```

setting the above prop to false will let you open all the link on the same webview and not jump to browser